# Is there a more pythonic way to assign values in list to multiple StringVars in a Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter

Hello I'm struggling to find a cleaner way to handle multiple StringVar assignments from a text file import. Whatever method I end up using needs to be adaptable for more StringVars in the future as this project grows.

Each line in the text file import has a key preceding a value "key: value" where the delimiter is ": ". While I currently have the order of the text file lines fixed, that will not be the case in the future for this project. Certain settings the program I'm making may influence what values are stored in this text file and some keys may not be written if there is no data associated with them.

From what I understand, I need the StringVars to fill in dynamic tkitner GUI Label and Entry elements so I don't see a way around using StringVars. Below is a snippet from my save-file import function which is assigns StringVar values from the input file data.

My current solution to manually set each StringVar to a value from a list is a bit clunky but better than a massive if-else statement evaluating the label which was my first pass.

```
    # Read in the data
    raw = open_regatta_save_file(file_path)

    # Process the regatta save file.
    row = 0   

    # Process Regatta Information
    regatta_labels = ["Regatta_Name", "Regatta_Host", "Regatta_Location", "Regatta_Start_Day",
                      "Regatta_Start_Month", "Regatta_Start_Year", "Regatta_End_Day", "Regatta_End_Month",
                      "Regatta_End_Year", "Regatta_Type", "Regatta_Throw_Outs"]
    regatta_values = [""] * len(regatta_labels)
    while raw[row] != ":::BOAT INFORMATION:::":  # Header for next section of input file
        line = raw[row]
        if ': ' in line and line.startswith(':::') is False:
            # This is a line with data in it and not a header
            [label, data] = line.split(': ')
            if data is None or data == '':
                # Either the provided data was blank or missing
                continue
            else:
                if label in regatta_labels:
                    label_index = regatta_labels.index(label)
                    regatta_values[label_index] = data
        row += 1

    # Set regatta parameter values. Since regatta_labels control the order of the regatta_values list,
    # these variables can be assigned in order.
    self.regatta_name.set(regatta_values[0])
    self.regatta_host.set(regatta_values[1])
    self.regatta_location.set(regatta_values[2])
    self.regatta_start_day.set(regatta_values[3])
    self.regatta_start_month.set(regatta_values[4])
    self.regatta_start_year.set(regatta_values[5])
    self.regatta_end_day.set(regatta_values[6])
    self.regatta_end_month.set(regatta_values[7])
    self.regatta_end_year.set(regatta_values[8])

    # Process Rest of file using similar method.
```

I'm hoping someone can help me understand Python StringVars better so that I can approach something simpler like:

```
StringVar1, StringVar2 ... = [list with values to assign to StringVars]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try using List/Dictionary of StringVars() then you can use the loop to set or get values

Comment: Do you mean like making temp stringvars in the while loop and filling the list and then just over-writting the tkinter stringvars?

Comment: yes filling it with  loop and then overwriting it with loop